# Problems with Biber/BibLaTeX in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: biblatex, biber

For reference, I'm using MiKTeX 2.9, 32-bit on Windows 7 64-bit. However, I tried this with the 64-bit version of MiKTeX and got an identical problem.

When trying to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tester.bib}
@ARTICLE {johndoe,
    author  = "John Doe",
    title   = "My Article",
    journal = "Journal",
    year    = "2000"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{tester.bib}

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Author}
\maketitle

This is a test document. Here \cite{johndoe} is a test citation.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get an error compiling using `latexmk`. The relevant parts of [the full console output](http://pastebin.com/bet0Qr9d) are the following lines:

```
Biber warning: [168] Utils.pm:147> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9
---
Package biblatex Warning: File 'tester.bbl' is wrong format version - expected
2.6.

(tester.bbl
! Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition.
l.21   \sortlist{
                 nty}{nty}
?
```

Comment: I would make sure your TeX distribution is up-to-date – it feels like you have a version mismatch somehow. Did you recently update? If so, how? The example works fine for me with a standard latex/biber/latex/latex flow.

Comment: Your biber is too old. Make sure that you update as admin *and* as user.

Comment: After you have done that much needed update of Biber, you might have to delete the temporary (`.aux`, `.bbl`,  `.bcf`,`.blg`) files to be able to compile successfully.

Comment: I used a fresh install of MiKTeX, and immediately updated via the update tool. It still is giving me the same error

Comment: Did you run after the update the MiKTeX package manager? And did you it for admin and user (if you installed MiKTeX with the admin account?)

Comment: Any updates here? Did an update in both Admin and User mode help?

Comment: @moewe sorry for the delay in update! yes, it turns out the problem was just installing it for my particular user, and not system-wide